# Uniqueness of the inverse in a group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Does it follow from the group axioms that each element has exactly one inverse?
I.e. if $x$ is given then there is only one $x^{-1}$ for which $xx^{-1}=e$.

Comment: Yes. Suppose there are two distinct inverses, then prove that they must in fact be equal.

Comment: Are you defining an inverse element of a given $x$ as a $y$ such that $xy=e$ or as a $y$ such that $xy=e=yx$? This makes a world of difference, at least to me.

Comment: It's in very bad taste to treat $x^{-1}$ as a variable. The variable should be $x$ alone and after this theorem proved, then you earn the right to write $x^{-1}$.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it does.

*Proof:*
Let us assume that there was another inverse $y \neq x^{-1}$ for which $xy = e$, i.e. that there are more than one inverses of $x$. Then
$$
xx^{-1} = e = xy.
$$
Multiplying with $x^{-1}$ from the left, we get
$$
x^{-1} = \underbrace{x^{-1}x}_{e}x^{-1} = \underbrace{x^{-1}x}_{e}y = y.
$$
This contradicts our assumption, so $y = x$ must be true. From this follows that the inverse of $x$ is unique.

**Edit:** As commented below, this is a proof by contradiction starting from the contraposition $y \neq x^{-1}$. Actually, you can also start directly from $xy = e$ and get the same conclusion.

Comment: You don't need the hypothesis $y\neq x^{-1}$, the proof works equally well without it.

Comment: How is it easier? Replace "Let us assume that there was another inverse $y \neq x^{-1}$" by "Let us assume that there are two inverse elements $y \neq$ and  $x^{-1}$" and keep the rest of the proof except for the "This contradicts our assumption" bit.

Comment: The $\neq$ after $y$ is a typo, it shouldn't be there.

Comment: In many cases proof by contradiction is powerful however here it just add unneccisery parts. One can just say "Let $y$ and $x^{-1}$ be inverses to $x$" and then show that they must be actually one and the same. No contradiction is needed

Answer (score 0):

Not only does it follow from group axioms, it follows from [monoid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monoid) axioms (not every element needs to have inverse). Let $x\in M$ and let $y,z\in M$ be it's inverses, i.e. $xy = yx = e$ and $xz = zx = e$. Then $$y = ye = y(xz) = (yx)z = ez = z.$$